# trigger an event when a database entry meets a condition

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, h2, ebean

I am developing a Java play app (Ebean, H2). I have a Event model that has  Date properties.

```
@Entity
public class Event extends Model {

 @Id
 public Long id;

 @Constraints.MaxLength(500)
 public String description;

 @Constraints.Required
 @DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
 public Date start;

 @DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
 public Date end;

 ...
}
```

I want to trigger an event, whenever an entry in my Event table, reaches the current system time but I do not know the best(efficient) way to do it.

for example, is it possible that the ebean informs me, whenever an entry in the database reaches the current system time?

Comment: It's hardly difficult to assign action to model....But instead of it you can use Akka.scheduler to schedule an action for given date. This scheduler setup task in the future whenever you would try save this model.

Comment: this is actually what I ended up doing, every minute I do query from the whole table and return those entries that meet "start<now<end" (means that this event is happening).  I don't like it because I think its a waste of resources.

Comment: true and there is another problem. if you restart your server all scheduled task will be removed so it is possible to lose it very quickly. hmmm...maybe a smarter person have better solution

Comment: I start my scheduled task in onStart(),  so i think it should continue workung after the restart?